# Existence of fixed point on Banach space

Tags: banach-fixed-point

I need your help please:
If $(X,\|\cdot\|_{X})$ is a Banach space, $A:X\times X\times
X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a trilinear form. Suppose that $A$ is
continuous,i.e., there exists $M>0$ such that $$|A(w,u,v)|\leq
M\|w\|_{X}\|u\|_{X}\|v\|_{X}\quad\forall w,u,v\in X$$ Besides for
all $w\in X$, $A(w,\cdot,\cdot)$ is elliptical,i.e., there exists
$\alpha>0$ independent of $w$ such that
$$A(w,v,v)\geq\alpha\|v\|_{X}^{2}\quad\forall v\in X$$
If $F\in X'$ and $T:X\rightarrow X$ the operator define by $T(w)=u$
with $u\in X$ the only element that $A(w,u,v)=F(v)\quad\forall v\in
X$.\
Also define $K:=\{w\in X /\|w\|_{X}\leq\frac{1}{\alpha}\|F\|_{X'}\}$
and suppose that $\frac{M}{\alpha^2}\|F\|_{X'}<1$. Prove that there
exists a unique $u\in K$ such that $T(u)=u$

Comment: Show that $T$ maps $K$ to $K$ and that the inequalities are what make $T$ a contraction, so it has a unique fixed point.

Comment: You can post your solution and accept it for future users